# Return summary table that sums data with iteration and control statement

Tags: r

none of these functions are particularly hard to do, but I'm wondering how to combine them.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(index = seq(1:8),
                 amps = c(7, 6, 7, 0, 7, 6, 0, 6))
```

As long as there is a positive value for amps, I'd like to sum them up. If amps = 0, then that's a break in the sequence and I'd like to return the 0, then start over. I'd also like to return the corresponding index value. The result would look like this:

```
index  amps
<dbl> <dbl>
1     1    20
2     4     0
3     5    13
4     7     0
5     8     6
```

I can do this in VBA but I'd like to beef up my R skills in functional programming. I would prefer to use functions rather than loops just because they're cleaner. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another base R solution using  `rle` + `tapply`

```
u <- with(rle(df$amps == 0), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
dfout <- data.frame(
    index = which(!duplicated(u)),
    amps = tapply(df$amps, u, sum)
)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  index amps
1     1   20
2     4    0
3     5   13
4     7    0
5     8    6
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = with(rle(amps == 0), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 summarise(index = first(index),
           amps = sum(amps))

    grp index  amps
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1    20
2     2     4     0
3     3     5    13
4     4     7     0
5     5     8     6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new group where  `amps = 0` or where previous value of `amps` is 0, get the first value of `index` and `sum` of `amps` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(amps == 0 | lag(amps, default = first(amps)) == 0)) %>%
  summarise(index = first(index), amps = sum(amps)) %>%
  select(-gr)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  index  amps
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1    20
#2     4     0
#3     5    13
#4     7     0
#5     8     6
```

---

Using the same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(index = first(index), amps = sum(amps)), 
               cumsum(amps == 0 | shift(amps, fill = first(amps)) == 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R we could use `aggregate` based on the `rle`.

```
ll <- rle(df$amps != 0)$lengths
rr <- aggregate(amps ~ cbind(index=rep(index[!!c(amps[1]>0, diff(amps!=0))], ll)), df, sum) 
rr
#   index amps
# 1     1   20
# 2     4    0
# 3     5   13
# 4     7    0
# 5     8    6
```